# Unable to display image from the byteArray

Tags: android, xamarin

I am not able to display the image which is in form byte array.

xaml code :

```
 <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="20, 10" Spacing="10" >
        <Image Source="{Binding ScannedImage}"/>
 </StackLayout>

View Model:

public void HandleImagereceived(object sender, byte[] byteImage)
{
           var image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(byteImage));
           ScannedImage = image
}

 public ImageSource ScannedImage
 {
        get { return scannedImage; }
        set
        {
           scannedImage = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("ScannedImage");
        }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to display the image on a blank screen? set the image to the content of the page, without a layout as a parent. The image might be too big to display because of the stacklayout padding.

Comment: So I should I remove the xaml binding completly. thanks

Comment: Thanks so much that was the reason . Assigning it directly yo the content page worked .